# nestjs logging service for JEST

Tags: logging, jestjs, nestjs

I have a problem to view log inside nestjs when execute in Jest. I can setup to see logger when running nestjs fine But when running via Jest. The logger is not print out on screen.

Below is the code that using to setup testing module.

```
const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
  imports: [HttpModule, ScheduleModule.forRoot()],
  controllers: [ExampleController],
  providers: [ExampleService, Logger],
}).compile();

module.useLogger(['error', 'warn', 'log', 'debug', 'verbose']);
```

And in ExampleController

```
import { Controller, Get, Logger } from '@nestjs/common';

@Controller('example')
export class ExampleController {
  private readonly logger = new Logger(ExampleController.name);

  @Get()
  getExample(): string {
    this.logger.debug('example');
    return 'example';
  }
}
```

This debug message is not shown when running on Jest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Late answer, but I just ran into the same issue and ended up solving it through adding:

```
module.useLogger(new ConsoleLogger());
```

Hope it helps someone. `ConsoleLogger` is imported from `@nestjs/common`

Comment: Thanks Agus, it can be chained before compile as well. e.g: `Test.createTestingModule({...}).setLogger(new ConsoleLogger()).compile()`